# Is there a Skype plugin that uses TLS and ZRTP

Tags: tls, skype

I'm curious, if one can upgrade the security Skype offers to avoid a man in the middle snooping in on the calls by both parties using a client side plugin? Does one exist for this purpose?

A bit of background reading:

- [The Daily Dot: New FBI surveillance unit focuses on Skype and wireless communications](http://www.dailydot.com/news/fbi-going-dark-internet-wiretapping-unit/)
- [RandomBit.net: Skype backdoor confirmation](http://lists.randombit.net/pipermail/cryptography/2013-May/004224.html)
- [Neowin.net: FBI: Monitoring Skype and Gmail are "top priority" in 2013](http://www.neowin.net/news/fbi-monitoring-skype-and-gmail-are-top-priority-in-2013)

Comment: Skype _already_ does that.

Comment: Skype has a backdoor for the FBI. So no I do not trust their implementation

Comment: Then use http://crypto.cat/

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't any plugin for Skype that would plug into its transport layer and custom encrypt calls peer-to-peer, and there likely won't be any as:

> Skype uses a closed proprietary protocol, which they do not publish. Skype intentionally does not interoperate with the rest of the VoIP industry, which is built on open standards. <sup>[[1]](http://zfoneproject.com/faq.html#skype)</sup>

Skype is now fighting back to regain its reputation and end users' trust, after the series of news stories, such as you link to, have alleged that: *Skype changed its network's architecture since its acquisition by Microsoft last year to enable “lawful interception” of calls.*

> <sup>**Mark Gillett, Skype COO:**</sup>
>   *"Skype to Skype calls do not flow through our
>   data centres and the "supernodes" are not involved in passing media
>   (audio or video) between Skype clients.   These calls continue to be
>   established directly between participating Skype nodes (clients). In
>   some cases, Skype has added servers to assist in the establishment,
>   management or maintenance of calls."*

Well, right. *Managed calls* anyone?!

TL;DR - Since Skype is using a proprietary *hybrid* TLS (combining both *client-server* and *peer-to-peer* encryption protocols, [and not that safe ones at that either](http://zfoneproject.com/faq.html#vbr)), I don't see them opening up to the wider VoIP community and supporting custom encryption schemes and [ZRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZRTP).

Comment: Is there a VOIP you would recommend that does present my requested features?

Comment: @CharlesHoskinson - It's hard to give any direct recommendation not knowing your requirements. You could investigate your options on your own by starting with this [Comparison of VoIP software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_VoIP_software). Honestly though, short of cashing out for some paid solution the choice is rather limited, if A/V is a requirement. Personally, I use [Google Talk w/ video chat plugin](http://www.google.com/talk/index.html) (alternatively, you could try [Hangouts](http://www.google.com/hangouts/)) in OTR mode, but not for highly confidential stuff. :?